# JS: how to capture output of a function every time it gets called

Tags: javascript

I have the following self-invoked function which is being utilized by the other functions across the app:

```
var Api = (function() {
  var requestPayload;
  var responsePayload;

  return {
    getRequestPayload: function() {
      return requestPayload;
    },
    setRequestPayload: function(newPayloadStr) {
      requestPayload = JSON.parse(newPayloadStr);
    },
    getResponsePayload: function() { // <-Function's output I need
      return responsePayload;
    },
    setResponsePayload: function(newPayloadStr) {
      responsePayload = JSON.parse(newPayloadStr);
    }
  };           
}());
```

This function is called by other functions in the app like:

```
Api.getResponsePayload();
```

I want to capture the output of `getResponsePayload` function every time this function is called to utilize is for further processing.

I tried to create another function:

```
function runMe(responsePayload) {
    console.log(responsePayload)
}
```

And it gets called everytime `getResponsePayload` function is called but the output I'm getting is `undefined`:

```
getResponsePayload: function() {
    runMe();
return responsePayload;
```

How can I get the output of `getResponsePayload` function everytime it gets called by any other function in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shim it, assuming this is for debug purposes. You may want to handle exceptions more explicitly, just be sure to rethrow to be transparent.

```
Api.getResponsePayload = (function(previousFn){
  return function() {
    var result = previousFn.apply(this, arguments);
    // print them or something
    return result;
  }
})(Api.getResponsePayload)
```

Edit: Here is a generalisation of the method above:

```
function logMethodCallsOn(object, methodName) {
  var actualMethod = object[methodName];
  object[methodName] = function() {
    var title = methodName + "(" + Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function (val) { return JSON.stringify(val); }).join(", ") + ")";
    try {
      var result = actualMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      console.log(title + " =", result);
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(title + " threw", e);
      throw(e);
    }
  }
}

logMethodCallsOn(Api, 'getResponsePayload');
logMethodCallsOn(Api, 'setResponsePayload');
```

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: Thank you ; you can find out more about similar concepts from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)

Answer (score 2):

You could use callbacks. I'm not sure if you whant a callback in the get or the set, this example shows both.

[Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904074/1977018) is more elegant and can be used even if `Api` is an external object. But I think this simpler implementation could be useful for learning purpose.

```js
var Api = (function(getResponsePayloadCallback, setResponsePayloadCallback) {
  var requestPayload;
  var responsePayload;

  return {
 getRequestPayload: function() {
   return requestPayload;
 },
 setRequestPayload: function(newPayloadStr) {
   requestPayload = JSON.parse(newPayloadStr);
 },
 getResponsePayload: function() { // <-Function's output I need
   getResponsePayloadCallback(responsePayload);
   return responsePayload;
 },
 setResponsePayload: function(newPayloadStr) {
   responsePayload = JSON.parse(newPayloadStr);
   setResponsePayloadCallback(responsePayload);
 }
  };           
})(getResponsePayloadHandler, setResponsePayloadHandler);

Api.setResponsePayload('{ "foo": "foo value" }');
var requestPayload = Api.getResponsePayload();

function getResponsePayloadHandler(value) {
  console.log("getResponsePayload: " + value.foo);
}

function setResponsePayloadHandler(value) {
  console.log("setResponsePayload: " + value.foo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ; It can also be done with a conditional breakpoint, which really it should if this is for debug and not audit =) Not sure that particular API is worth improving lol

Comment: Thanks you, Eric's solution did the trick for me but yours is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any parameter to `runMe` so it logs undefined. Change your `getResponsePayload` function to:

```
getResponsePayload: function() {
    runMe(responsePayload);
    return responsePayload;
}
```

Anyway be aware that if you don't set `responsePayload`, you console output will still be undefined cause `responsePayload` is only declared but never assigned a value (so it will have `undefined` value)

Comment: I believe it may be a typo. But let's see how OP responds to your solution. :)

Comment: Yes it worked for me and I have been kind of stupid today. Is there any better way of doing what am I trying to do? Somehow I dont feel good with calling runMe() function inside that function. Any suggestions?